# I have a canvas that I'd like to generate random rectangles on. I can't seem to get it to work

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload {
function rectWidth() {
    var width = document.getElementById('Canvas').offsetWidth;
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}
function rectHeight() {
    var width = document.getElementById('Canvas').offsetHeight;
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 2);
}
function randColor() {
    var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
return rectWidth;
return rectHeight;
return randColor;
$(#rect).html("<rect width="return rectWidth;" height="return rectHeight" style=""color="return randColor"/>")}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="Canvas" width="900" height="200">
<rect id="rect" width="250" height="250" style="color=blue"/></canvas>
```

I'm just trying to figure out how I can change the width, height, and color of the rectangle.

Position will come next.

How would I change my code to get it to work?

Comment: that is not how you draw on a canvas. you can't draw rectanles on a canvas using html. it has to be done with javascript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rect

Comment: Tried. Still not working though.

http://codepen.io/PCMRwill0956/pen/LRNyyJ

Comment: will - if my answer helped you please hit the checkmark by the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of how to draw a rectangle on canvas:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    var width = 10;
    var height = 10;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF0000";
    ctx.rect(x, y, width, height);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
```

Here's a quick fiddle which draws randomly sized, randomly colored rectangles on the canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/6omtu0pg/

Comment: Just tried it. I got 

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

in Chrome

Comment: the ID you're using in getElementById is wrong or your code is running before the DOM is ready. feel free to post a new question with your new code if you need further help as this is a different, unrelated problem.